# rails recaptcha error: We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. it return false all the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I have this recaptcha error We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information.

I did everything exactly but its still there recaptcha checkbox return false even after I checked the button

Here is my codes:

In gemfile

```
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
```

in config in in initializer in recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key   = 'my site key'
  config.secret_key = 'my secret key' 
end
```

In view:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
```

In controller:

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_attributes)
  if verify_recaptcha(model: @contact) && @contact.save
    ContactMailer.message_send(@contact).deliver
    redirect_to contacts_path, notice: "Thank you... Your Message was sent successfully."
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Please correct the form"
    render :index
  end
end
```

I even try this in recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key = ENV["RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY"]
  config.private_key = ENV["RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY"]
end
```

but I got this error

```
undefined method `public_key=' for #<Recaptcha::Configuration:0x00007fc132b363e8> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  public_send
```

In this link https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
I have
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "missing-input-response",
    "missing-input-secret"
  ]
}

Not sure what to do please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you put `<%= recaptcha_tags %>`?

As per: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/configuration.rb

You can:

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key   = 'my site key'
  config.secret_key = 'my secret key' 
end
```

other wise the gem will automatically pick it from `ENV['RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY']` and `ENV['RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY']`.

This won't work:

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key = ENV["RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY"]
  config.private_key = ENV["RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY"]
end
```

My doubts now goes towards that you place `recaptcha_tags` in a wrong place (maybe out of the form). that it does not get sent to the controller/backend.

Comment: No it's inside the form

Comment: Do you think I have to add some codes in the controller?

Comment: Noway this is the solution :D I spent four days trying to figure it out Thank you sooo much :D